# Is there any way to control Mac volume from Apple Watch?

Tags: macos, ios, audio, apple-watch, watchos

Is there a way to control a Mac's audio volume from Apple Watch? Apple didn't provide Watch functionality for system-wide Mac volume adjusting as far as I know.

NB: The only so-so way I've found is if audio is playing from Mac iTunes, and the iPhone/Watch is paired with that library via Home Sharing. The volume can then be changed with the Watch *Remote* app – but that doesn't trigger *system-wide* volume. It only changes iTunes' in-app volume.

Is there some third-party software for iOS/WatchOS that can accomplish this?

Note about iPhones: I know that the iOS app [BTT Remote](http://bttremote.com/) can control a Mac's volume, but unfortunately there is no Watch app for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used MacID with great success on my Pebble smartwatch but they also have support for Apple Watch. It's $4 but TOTALLY worth it!

https://macid.co/

The watch app requires the companion iPhone app to sync with the desktop app and control the volume and track selection.

And that's not all, the iPhone to Mac has a proximity sensor so you can set your computer to unlock AS YOU APPROACH IT and lock if you get up to walk away.

I hope this answer helps :)

Comment: This is a slick tool - some people have reported it’s not as reliable as Apple’s Watch unlock, but the price is low enough to be a throw away if it doesn’t pan out for you.

Comment: Yea I must admit that it used to much more reliable. Since the latest macOS updates I've noticed that occasionally I need to reconnect the desktop/mobile apps which sometimes requires forgetting the device and re-adding it. Again, it's not consistent or all that frequent and I hope that the developers see to fixing it.

Comment: MacID volume control stopped working for me on recent MacOS/WatchOS. Don't know if it was fixable, but I spent perhaps 30-40 minutes trying to make it work and finally gave up and uninstalled MacID. I also tried the new software "Unlox" from the same developer and it didn't work. Might function for someone else though, but I will not recommend MacID at the moment.

Comment: MacID works for me after going to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility, then enabling the checkbox for MacID. Can confirm Unlox doesn't work, it doesn't have the UI elements on the watch app to control volume.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://cherpake.com/remote-for-mac/ Runs on the Mac, with companion apps on the iPhone and Watch. It's honestly not great, but it can do this.

Once you've set it up, changing the volume consists of launching the app on the Watch, selecting the computer (yes, it makes you choose it even if you only have one), selecting "KeyPad", selecting "Volume", then tapping volume buttons on the display. Turning the crown does nothing.

So it's not exactly super convenient.

The app also has rather annoying screens if you don't pay to unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that I've tried lately is [Homebridge](https://homebridge.io/) with the [homebridge-pc-volume](https://www.npmjs.com/package/homebridge-pc-volume) plugin. "pc" here includes Macs.

This exposes the computer volume in Siri and in Home.app. You can presumably even make automations involving it.

I've tried it out lately as a replacement for Remote for Mac (see other answer). It works pretty well.

My main annoyance is that it can hard to find this specific "device" in the Home.app on my watch, with many devices.